# Етимологія слова "конвікт"

Tags: етимологія

**Конвікт** - гуртожиток, пансіон; інтернат для учнів школи або колегіуму із досить суворим статутом; те саме, що й колегіум.

Приклад вживання ([джерело](http://expres.ua/news/2017/12/04/274773-velychna-istoriya-konviktu-navchaly-maybutnyu-elitu-sto-rokiv-tomu)):

> Велична історія **конвікту**: як навчали майбутню еліту сто років тому

Пошуки в СУМі та [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1985/EtSlUkrM_1985.pdf) не дали ніяких результатів, однак, можливо хтось із користувачів знає щось про походження даного слова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В російській мові теж є відповідне слово, хоча дещо [з іншим тлумаченням](//dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/20953/%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%92%D0%98%D0%9A%D0%A2):

- Конвикт (лат. convictus, від convivere — жити разом) — спільний стіл у вищих навчальних закладах, а також учні, яких утримують коштом держави або суспільства.

  > <sub>*Конвикт (лат. convictus, от convivere — жить вместе) — общий стол в высших учебных заведениях, а также ученики, содержимые на счет казны или общества* (Объяснение 25000 иностранных слов, вошедших в употребление в русский язык, с означением их корней. — Михельсон А.Д., 1865).</sub>
- Конвикт — гуртожиток навчального (зазвичай духовного католицького) закладу.

  > <sub>*Конвикт — общежитие при учебных (преимущ. духовн. католических) заведениях* (Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. — Павленков Ф., 1907).</sub>
- Конвикт (лат. convictus, від convivere — жити разом) — спільний стіл у вищих навчальних закладах, а також учні, яких утримують коштом держави чи за малу платню.

  > <sub>*Конвикт (лат. convictus, от convivere — жить вместе) — общий стол в высших учебных заведениях, а также ученики, содержимые на счет казны или за малую плату* (Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка. — Чудинов А.Н., 1910).</sub>

Хоча значення дещо інше, я припускаю, що походження українського слова може бути тим самим — від латинського *[convivere](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/convivere#Latin)* (*[convivo](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/convivo#Latin)*) — «жити разом» («я живу разом [з …]»).

До речі slovnyk.ua (не дуже авторитетне джерело, бо невідомо хто його складав; зазвичай він просто наводить статті із «Словника української мови» в 11 томах, але в цьому разі він дає власне тлумачення) каже, що в українського слова є [ще й інші значення](//www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%82), що більше перетинаються з відповідним російским словом (хоча це може виявитися просто перекладом вищеназваних російських словників):

> КОНВІКТ, -а, ч., іст. 1. Гуртожиток при навчальних (перев. духовних католицьких) закладах. 2. Загальний стіл у вищих навчальних закладах, а також учні, які утримуються за рахунок скарбниці або за малу плату.

Comment: Як ви гадаєте, чи не треба перекласти українською російське джерело? Може, залишити саме слово "конвикт" російською, а пояснення надати українською? Бо ви потім навіть не переказуєте значення того, що написано в цитаті, і людині, яка вчить українську, але не знає російську, буде складно зрозуміти, про що мова.

Comment: @P.Vovk, можливо, Ви праві. Але я наводив це в першу чергу задля «лат. convictus, от convivere» (що пояснено нижче). Але якщо наполягаєте — перекладу.

Comment: Як на мене, то в такому випадку можна було б цими дужками й обмежитися. Не наполягаю. Просто зробіть, будь ласка, як матимете сили.